# "projections are not allowed for immediate arguments of a supertype" Kotlin Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I am getting this error when I converted Java to Kotlin:

Java

```
public class HeaderTab extends ExpandableGroup {
    private String header;

    public HeaderTab(String title, List items) {
        super(title, items);
    }
}
```

Kotlin

```
class HeaderTab(title: String, items: List<*>) : ExpandableGroup<*>(title, items) {
    private val header: String? = null
}
```

Android Studio says this:

> projections are not allowed for immediate arguments of a supertype

What do I need to modify here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `Any` for a quick fix, or introduce a type parameter to make sure you don't break the type safety of the library.

`class HeaderTab(title: String, items: List<*>) : ExpandableGroup<Any>(title, items) {`

or

`class HeaderTab<E>(title: String, items: List<E>) : ExpandableGroup<E>(title, items) {`

The problem is that kotlin requires class types to be fully specified, so you can either specify a specific type as a type parameter or pass through a new type parameter.

Comment: Now wonder what the Kotlin team tried to do and whether they achieved what they wanted?! Probably not. There is always a quick fix to their "strict" rules that they think the Java core team failed (and fails) to solve. Almost same crap with different syntax and name